# IIS 7.5 Express New Virtual Dir

Tags: iis, iis-express

how do i add new virtual directory?

I'm getting error (The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found) but the files are all in /bin.

i have tried editing the applicationhost.config like this:

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        <virtualDirectory path="/SubFolderApp" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1\SubFolderApp" allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Comment: What is "xxx"? I don't see those letters in your example.

Comment: Although you have this problem with IIS Express (a Developer tool), I doubt the problem is any different from IIS. I voted to migrate this to serverfault.com

Comment: im sorry, xxx is just a .dll file in /bin. for example Facebook.dll . ohh sorry, i forgot about the existence of serverfault.com. or why is the tag even possible here ?

Comment: ohh yah, i forgot to tell that, if the app is in root folder, it can run all .dll files in /bin, but if the app is in a subfolder (/SubFolderApp), it will show the namespace not found error. so i suspected that any subfolder is not registered as an application. that is why im asking how to add new virtual dir so that i can have /SubFolderApp as a stand alone app instead of 1 app in root folder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to create a child application. Your configuration created child virtual directory. The configuration below turns /SubFolderApp into an application.

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
   </application>
   <application path="="/SubFolderApp" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1\SubFolderApp" />
   </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:localhost" />
   </bindings>
</site>
```

Comment: I think there's an extra `"=` in `path="="/SubFolderApp"`