# Angular 2 Visual Studio Setup Problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular

I followed the Angular2 VS setup from this page-

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

The issue is that `http://localhost:56428/` gives a 403 (forbidden) error, and the only way to access my index is to navigate to `http://localhost:56428/src/index.html`.

This is not ideal, and doesn't even work because requests to `system.js` and other files on this page go straight to the web root.

I'm not sure if I missed a step here but I don't think this is what they intended. How do I make `src/` servable at `/`?

**ANSWER FOUND AT**

[.net web application change root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424417/net-web-application-change-root-directory)

I don't know why the angular site does not mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER FROM**

[.net web application change root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424417/net-web-application-change-root-directory)

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        ...
        <urlMappings enabled="true">
             <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/src/index.html" />
        </urlMappings>
    </system.web>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect everything to root" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `base` tag:

> The  tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in
>   a document

.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: That would work. But all requests would still be prefixed by `src/` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked your index.html as application start up page?

If not, right click on index.html and click on "Set As Start Page".

Comment: I did. It goes to src/index.html in the browser